# Angular seed project - angular-loader-js dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angular seed, I add bootstrap to project

In index.html I use this script.

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

when I run npm run run update-index-async

thats generate this script section

```
    $script([
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
      'app.js'
    ]
```

but when I load index-async, I get "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery".

How can I managed dependencies with angular-loader.js. Is there any chance how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to answer to your question, in general we should avoid using `JQuery` or `Bootstrap` library usages whenever you can in an AngularJS application in order to get the out of the box functionality. Instead you can use `angular ui-bootstrap` as opposed to `Bootstrap`.
 
Whatever functionalities provided by `JQuery` can be easily yet in a more elegant way can be developed using `AngularJS`.
 In addition, `Angular` has an inbuilt `JQuery` library called `jqLite`.

There are series of angular-seed projects available in github. But each differs from another and addresses specific areas. Not majority of seed projects do contain most required implementations for a general project.

For jqlite refer these official docs links -

- [AngularJS FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)
- [Angular jqLite details](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

hence, I had generated a one which I used more often to generate my angularjs projects. Hope that helps you to follow and learn the project patterns and sample implementations. 
[AngularJS Seed Project](https://github.com/ugbandula/angular-seed).

Answer (score 0):

Could be because there is a conflict between the jquery lite used in angular. Use angular-material and only reference the bootstrap.css or checkout angular-bootsrap. It's best practice not to use JQuery with Angular.

[Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started)
[ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Can you give me some link please?